# D2007 IDE assertion failure when quitting app inside of IDE

Tags: delphi

I'm working on something at a client's site using D2007(CodeGear™ Delphi® 2007 for Win32®  Version 11.0.2902.10471). It's a new installation on a Windows 10(64bit) box.

When I hit -F2 or exit out of the program, I get this strange error dialog:

```
bds.exe - bordbk105N.dll

Assertion failure: "(!"SetThreadContext failed")" in ..\win32src\thread32.cpp at line 412
Continue execution?

[Yes] [No]
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1pM5.png)

If I click [Yes] it repeats. I can click [Yes] repeatedly for a while until it finally stops appearing.

If I click [No] then the IDE instantly closes.
Any suggestions on how to circumvent this?

Comment: What happens when you quit a brand new, empty, VCL app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue with Delphi 2007 on Windows 7+

There is an unofficial hotfix at https://cc.embarcadero.com/item/27521